# Combining 2 lists in strange way

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, nested-lists

Say I have these two lists of lists.

```
[[1.0, 100.0], [2.0, 100.0], [3.0, 100.0], [4.0, 100.0], [5.0, 100.0]]
[[1.0, 20.0], [2.0, 20.0], [3.0, 0.0]]
```

Note the different sizes, I want to combine them to create the list below

```
[[1.0, 100.0, 20.0], [2.0, 100.0, 20.0], [3.0, 100.0, 0.0], [4.0, 100.0], [5.0, 100.0]]
```

Their can be any number of lists and they can be of any length.

Comment: Where's your code, and what precisely is the problem with it? Please see [ask].

Comment: My code will not help in this situation. The question is clear. I want to combine the lists as shown. Nothing from the list can be assumed except each sublist will have only 2 elements. The first element being an identifier of sorts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want unique values and to combine any length lists:

```
from itertools import chain, izip_longest,ifilter
obj = object()
from collections import OrderedDict

print([list(ifilter(lambda x: x is not obj, OrderedDict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(tup))))
       for tup in (tup for tup in izip_longest(l1,l2,fillvalue=[obj]))])
```

Output:

```
[[1.0, 100.0, 20.0], [2.0, 100.0, 20.0], [3.0, 100.0, 0.0], [4.0, 100.0], [5.0, 100.0]]
```

If order is irrelevant you can call `set` on the tup instead of OrderedDict.